# CountDownTimer firing onTick at not excepted time point

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have the following `CountDownTimer`:

```
countdown = new CountDownTimer(10000, 5000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // Stuff here
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // Restart countdown
            countdown.start();
        }
    }.start();
```

As seen, there's a 5 seconds tick interval. But when this `CountDown` starts, the first interval occurs at 0 miliseconds.

Why my first tick is being fired at 0 miliseconds time, instead of 5000 miliseconds time?

Comment: CountDownTimer sets the tick all 5 seconds, starting with the first tic at the beginning. To avoid this, make a simple if statement, like if(millisUntilFinished>0){//do Your stuff inside if statement};

Comment: @Opiatefuchs that won't work, millilUntilFinished is _not_ 0 on `start()` it's "somewhere near" the desired countdown time, but not necessarily always equal to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Countdown timer starts from a second after it is supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783313/countdown-timer-starts-from-a-second-after-it-is-supposed-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the documentation has to say about `onTick()` is "Callback fired on regular interval."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#onTick(long)

Why are you assuming it shouldn't fire immediately?

If want to ignore the first callback to `onTick()` you could add a boolean flag like so:

```
countdown = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        private boolean first = true;
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                return;
            }
            // Stuff here
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // Restart countdown
            first = true;
            countdown.start();
        }
    }.start();
```

After looking at your usage of `CountDownTimer` a bit more it seems like you could also use a `Handler` / `Runnable` combination.

Here's an example:

In your `Activity` you do:

```
private Handler timerHandler;
private Runnable timerRunnable;

// ...

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    timerHandler = new Handler();
    timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Stuff here
            timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 5000);
        }
    };
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 5000);
}
```

Comment: That's what I ended doing. A bit ugly, but solves my first tick.
I assume is not starting immediately because it says nothing about that.

Comment: @Sonhja I've edited my answer again, you could use a `Handler` / `Runnable` too, might be a bit neater if it fits your needs.

Comment: yes, I can use a `Handler` / `Runnable`, but I want to repeat my timer, not only once. So I think I will keep for the moment your first solution.

Comment: If you look at the `Runnable` you'll see that it posts itself again at the end, so I think it is what you want, but whatever you think, it's your question.

Comment: Oh I see... Thanks for both solutions! :)