# Countdown timer starts from a second after it is supposed to

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a Countdowntimer object. Basically the timer is supposed to countdown from 10 to 1. What it does is starts the timer from 9 and it ends on 1 but it stays on 1 for about 2 seconds... Why does this happen. I've made sure that my timer is not overlapping/getting called twice in a row as that could be the cause. This is part of my timer object.

```
new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.d("timer","Actual: " + Long.toString(millisUntilFinished)+".... "+Long.toString(millisUntilFinished/1000));
            time.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }
```

This is what I am getting from the Log.d outputs:

```
03-03 21:23:15.438 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 9964.... 9
03-03 21:23:16.453 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 8949.... 8
03-03 21:23:17.463 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 7939.... 7
03-03 21:23:18.473 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 6929.... 6
03-03 21:23:19.482 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 5919.... 5
03-03 21:23:20.493 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 4909.... 4
03-03 21:23:21.503 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 3899.... 3
03-03 21:23:22.513 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 2889.... 2
03-03 21:23:23.523 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 1879.... 1
03-03 21:23:25.436 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 9978.... 9
03-03 21:23:26.453 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 8961.... 8
03-03 21:23:27.463 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 7951.... 7
03-03 21:23:28.473 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 6941.... 6
03-03 21:23:29.483 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 5931.... 5
03-03 21:23:30.493 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 4921.... 4
03-03 21:23:31.503 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 3911.... 3
03-03 21:23:32.514 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 2900.... 2
03-03 21:23:33.522 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 1891.... 1
03-03 21:23:35.431 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 9994.... 9
03-03 21:23:36.443 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 8982.... 8
03-03 21:23:37.454 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 7971.... 7
03-03 21:23:38.463 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 6961.... 6
03-03 21:23:39.474 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 5951.... 5
03-03 21:23:40.493 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 4932.... 4
03-03 21:23:41.503 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 3922.... 3
03-03 21:23:42.513 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 2912.... 2
03-03 21:23:43.523 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 1902.... 1
03-03 21:23:45.456 1947-1947/com.w1481217.braintraninggame D/timer: Actual: 9978.... 9
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the ticks don't come in at perfectly precise intervals as maybe expected.  In your case, the value of `millisUntilFinished` in consecutive `onTick` callbacks isn't guaranteed to be 10000, 9000, ..., 0.

The first tick doesn't have 9 seconds (or 9000ms) remaining, it has 9964ms.   So, only 36ms has passed from the time you called `start()` on the `CountDownTimer` to the time of this first tick callback.  Chris' comment on his answer that the "first callback happens after 1000ms" seems to be incorrect (I'd make a comment on his answer, but I don't have the rep!).  You're seeing 9 in your text view and log statement because of the classic integer division problem.  You're not seeing the additional 0.964 seconds because the result of the division is of type `long`, which does not have a fractional part.  Try using `1000.0` as your divisor in the log statement and remove the `Long.toString()` and see what value is shown.

In regards to the hanging towards the end of the countdown, see the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12283400/1244019

Depending on how precise you want your timer, perhaps a solution to your problem would be to keep a counter within your `CountDownTimer`, updating your TextView and decrementing the counter each time `onTick` is called.  See the following:

```
new CountDownTimer(11500, 1000) {
    int i = 10;
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Log.d("timer","Time left: " + i);
        // Update TextView
        i--;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() { }
}.start();
```

Comment: Yeah I wondering the same thing about Chris's comment. Anyways, I have tried dividing the time but no use. I guess making the timer start from 11000ms to 1000ms is reasonable since it practically does start the timer from 10 if I divide the time by 1000. And the total time lapsed is still 10 seconds. Seem like a botch fix to me though... but nonetheless it got the mistake fixed!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the time interval isn't fine enough and callback isn't at exactly quantas of 10,000

This code in Kotlin is presenting the remaining time punctuately:

```
private fun startTimer()
{
    Log.d(TAG, ":startTimer: timeString = '$timeString'")

    object : CountDownTimer(TASK_SWITCH_TIMER, 250)
    {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long)
        {
            val secondsUntilFinished : Long = 
            Math.ceil(millisUntilFinished.toDouble()/1000).toLong()
            val timeString = "${TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(secondsUntilFinished)}:" +
                    "%02d".format(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(secondsUntilFinished))
            Log.d(TAG, ":startTimer::CountDownTimer:millisUntilFinished = $ttlseconds")
            Log.d(TAG, ":startTimer::CountDownTimer:millisUntilFinished = $millisUntilFinished")
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onFinish()
        {
            timerTxtVw.text = "0:00"
            gameStartEndVisibility(true)
        }
    }.start()
}
```